# wget does not terminate

Tags: linux, wget

I have the following problem with my code:

After the downloads are all finished the script does not terminate. It seems to wait for more urls.

---

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"
test=$(wget -qO- "$3" | grep --line-buffered "tarball_url" | cut -d '"' -f4)

echo test:
echo $test
echo ==============

wget -nd -N -q --trust-server-names --content-disposition -i- ${test}
```

An example for `$test`:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/matrixssl/matrixssl/tarball/3-9-1-open https://api.github.com/repos/matrixssl/matrixssl/tarball/3-9-0-open
```

Comment: `-i-` means to read the list of URLs from standard input. So it's waiting for you to type the URLs.

Comment: Yes, and as I wrote this works, but how do I terminate it? `$test` contains the urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-i` means to get the list of URLs from a file, and using `-` in place of the file means to get them from standard input. So it's waiting for you to type the URLs.

If `$test` contains the URLs, you don't need to use `-i`, just list the URLs on the command line:

```
wget -nd -N -q --trust-server-names --content-disposition $test
```

Comment: Guess I misunderstood the docs, I thought one could only process multiple urls in combination with `-i`